# Loop to find probability in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to run a loop in a large dataset in R. The goal of the loop is to be able to find the proportion of participants exposed to an agent "B" knowing that they are exposed to an agent "A". In other terms, I am trying to calculate P(B|A) for all cells in a given dataframe.

It is fairly easy to do this by hand in a small dataset where a "1" means an exposure :

```
df <-data.frame(ID = c(1:10),
                Agent_A = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                Agent_B = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1),
                Agent_C = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                Agent_D = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1))

# Find the total that are exposed to agent A 
sumcol <- sum(df$Agent_A==1)

# Find the total that are exposed to A and B/C/D 
sum_AB <- sum(df$Agent_A==1 & df$Agent_B==1)
sum_AC <- sum(df$Agent_A==1 & df$Agent_C==1)
sum_AD <- sum(df$Agent_A==1 & df$Agent_D==1)

# Find the ratio of exposed to A and B/C/D among those exposed to A
# P(B | A)
sum_AB/sumcol
sum_AC/sumcol
sum_AD/sumcol
```

However, my real dataframe is too large to even consider doing it this way. After looking online, I know that a loop is probably the appropriate solution to this problem.

It seems that I need to have a loop to look at all the columns and a loop within that one that looks at all the rows, but I am unable to do so.

The loop I have been trying does not give me the results I want :

```
for(i in colnames(df)){
print(sum(colnames(df[[i]])==1)}
```

**What would be a loop that gives me a dataframe with the expected P(B|A)?**

Any explanation and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As all three answerers have suggested, a good rule of thumb when working in R is "If I'm thinking of using a loop, there's probably a better way to do it".  It's also helpful to make sure your data frame is [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) (even if you aren't using the tidyverse).  here, your data frame is not tidy because it includes data (the agnet id) in your column names.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Still learning how to use R in the most efficient way.

Comment: most of the solutions provided just look for the ratio w.r.t A. the solution i provide below gives the result w.r.t all agents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this for everyone. ie B/A, A/B etc.. Each row will represent the desired ratio results. Note that these are not mutually exclusive thus their sum is not necessarily 1. eg check row 2

```
`diag<-`( b <- crossprod(as.matrix(df[-1])), 0)/diag(b)

          Agent_A   Agent_B   Agent_C Agent_D
Agent_A 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.4000000    0.40
Agent_B 0.2500000 0.0000000 0.0000000    1.00
Agent_C 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0.25
Agent_D 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.1666667    0.00
```

You could also use `combn`.

```
combn(df[-1],2, \(x) sum(x[[1]]*x[[2]])/colSums(x), simplify = F)
[[1]]
Agent_A Agent_B 
   0.20    0.25 

[[2]]
Agent_A Agent_C 
    0.4     0.5 

[[3]]
  Agent_A   Agent_D 
0.4000000 0.3333333 

[[4]]
Agent_B Agent_C 
      0       0 

[[5]]
  Agent_B   Agent_D 
1.0000000 0.6666667 

[[6]]
  Agent_C   Agent_D 
0.2500000 0.1666667
```

For each result, we get the ratio of those exposed to the first one among the second and those exposed to the second among the first. Compare with the matrix results obtained

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu, the combn method does seem to give me all the possible pairs and their associated ratio. Do you know if there is a way to represent this data in a table rather than a list? I tried to use as.data.frame() or as.matrix() and it does not seem to be digest information. I need to be able to extract the pairs with a correlation > than a threshold x.

Comment: @JérômeFortier yes, you can represent as a tabular format. The question is in what way do you want the tabular format? the first method i provided does give a tabular format. I just dont know what tabular format you need. eg try also `na.omit(as.data.frame.table(\`diag<-\`( b <- crossprod(as.matrix(df[-1])), NA)/diag(b)))`

Comment: Ideally a table with agents in rows and in columns, ie to represent the pairs created with combn. I tried as.data.frame.table and R as.data.frame.table(combn(df[-1],2, \(x) sum(x[[1]]*x[[2]])/colSums(x), simplify = F)) but this gives me an error message.

Comment: @JérômeFortier I do not understand what your table should look like. So far I have given you two tables, ie by using `as.data.frame.table` function, and the one represented in the solution. You should consider editing your question to include how the final solution/table should look like. I am unable to visualize what you want

Comment: @JérômeFortier the result given by `combn` and the results given by `crossprod` is the same. So you can use whichever is easier to refer to

Comment: You are right, the crossprod method gives me exactly what I want with as.data.frame.table. I have the pairs of agents and their correlation. Thanks a lot for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R way with `colMeans`.
I also include a results check. `cp_method` gives wrong results, as can be seen in the end. And since I was checking, I also include the timings, copied from [DaveArmstrong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77544882/8245406).

**The fastest** solution is [AndS.' Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77545075/8245406) one.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(data.table)
  library(Rcpp)
})

colmeans_method <- function() {
  colMeans(dat[which(dat[[1L]] == 1), -1L])
}
cp_method <- function(){
  crossprod(mat[,1], mat[,-1])/sum(mat[,1])
}

set.seed(2023)
ncol <- 1000
nrow <- 1000
mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), ncol*nrow, replace=TRUE), ncol=ncol)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1), ncol*nrow, replace=TRUE), ncol=ncol))
datDT <- dat
setDT(datDT)

library(microbenchmark)
mb <- microbenchmark(
  Get_Prob(dat),
  colmeans_method(),
  cp_method(),
  tidy_method(),
  dt_method(),
  subset_method()
)
print(mb, order = "median")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>               expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq
#>      Get_Prob(dat)   3.289101   3.597452   4.028873   3.772701   4.067351
#>        cp_method()   5.813102   6.461552   8.610371   6.844751  10.073400
#>    subset_method()   8.099901   9.278351  12.277170  11.272801  14.272951
#>  colmeans_method()   9.175901  10.972902  13.759671  12.364301  13.601401
#>        dt_method()  69.069600  76.803101  95.679720  81.741551  96.598951
#>      tidy_method() 188.440501 205.032301 220.476604 212.181001 230.616351
#>       max neval  cld
#>    7.8464   100 a   
#>   26.1239   100 ab  
#>   23.4447   100  b  
#>   87.5997   100  b  
#>  193.3119   100    d
#>  313.9086   100   c

dt_method() |> head() |> as.data.frame() -> dtm
names(dtm)[2] <- "dt_method"
cbind(
  Rcpp = Get_Prob(dat) |> head(),
  colmeans_method = colmeans_method() |> as.matrix() |> head(),
  tidy_method = tidy_method() |> t() |> head(),
  dt_method = dtm[-1],
  subset_method = subset_method() |> as.matrix() |> head(),
  cp_method = cp_method() |> t() |> head()
)
#>         Rcpp colmeans_method tidy_method dt_method subset_method cp_method
#> V2 0.4951076       0.4951076   0.4951076 0.4951076     0.4951076 0.4742063
#> V3 0.4716243       0.4716243   0.4716243 0.4716243     0.4716243 0.5019841
#> V4 0.5048924       0.5048924   0.5048924 0.5048924     0.5048924 0.5178571
#> V5 0.5029354       0.5029354   0.5029354 0.5029354     0.5029354 0.4761905
#> V6 0.5088063       0.5088063   0.5088063 0.5088063     0.5088063 0.4722222
#> V7 0.4892368       0.4892368   0.4892368 0.4892368     0.4892368 0.4781746
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A loop is not the best solution here.  There are a few ways to do this, but one way is to 'reshape' your dataset into a long format, and then calculate the mean of the `exposed` variable for each level of `agent` subject to `Agent_A` being 1.

The code below uses the `data.table` library to achieve this.  Have a look at the intermediate `df_long` object to make sense of it.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df_long <- melt(df, id.vars=c("ID", "Agent_A"), 
                    variable.name = "agent", 
                    value.name = "exposed")

df_long[Agent_A==1, mean(exposed), by=agent]

   variable  V1
1:  Agent_B 0.2
2:  Agent_C 0.4
3:  Agent_D 0.4
```

Edit:

There's a far easier way to do this:

```
> subset(df, Agent_A==1)[,-c(1,2)] |> sapply(mean)

Agent_B Agent_C Agent_D 
    0.2     0.4     0.4
```

Here I've dropped all the `Agent_A==0` rows, then just found the mean of each column except the first two.

Answer (score 1):

Using the tidyverse for convenience; no explicit loop writing needed.
If you had more agents to the right of the original frame they would be included.

```
df <-data.frame(ID = c(1:10),
                Agent_A = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                Agent_B = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1),
                Agent_C = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                Agent_D = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1))

library(tidyverse)

# still a good first step...
# Find the total that are exposed to agent A 
sumcol <- sum(df$Agent_A==1)

summarise(df,
          across(-c(ID,Agent_A),\(x){
            sum(Agent_A == 1 & x==1)/sumcol
            }))
```

across`()` first condition is telling to do the process for every column that isnt the ID, or the Agent_A

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a loop, maybe you could write it using `Rcpp` for speed. Something like this would work (no promises that this is the most efficient method). Maybe @DaveArmstrong can benchmark it too.

```r
library(Rcpp)

df <-data.frame(ID = c(1:10),
                Agent_A = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                Agent_B = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1),
                Agent_C = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                Agent_D = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1))

cppFunction('
  Rcpp::NumericVector Get_Prob( Rcpp::DataFrame df){
    
    int total = 0;
    int B = 0;
    int C = 0;
    int D = 0;
    
    Rcpp::NumericVector a = df[1];
    Rcpp::NumericVector b = df[2];
    Rcpp::NumericVector c = df[3];
    Rcpp::NumericVector d = df[4];
    
    for( int i = 0; i < df.nrows(); i++){
        if(a[i] == 1){
          total += 1;
          B += b[i];
          C += c[i];
          D += d[i];
        }
    }
    
    float pB = (float)B/(float)total;
    float pC = (float)C/(float)total;
    float pD = (float)D/(float)total;
    
    Rcpp::NumericVector probs{pB, pC, pD};
    
    return probs;
  
  }
')


Get_Prob(df)
#[1] 0.2 0.4 0.4
```

---

## Edit

It is not difficult to adapt the function above to the general case of more than 4 columns. The function below does that and is the fastest of the solutions.

```r
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
  Rcpp::NumericVector Get_Prob(Rcpp::DataFrame X){

    Rcpp::NumericVector a = X[0];
    Rcpp::NumericVector probs(X.ncol() - 1);

    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        if(a[i] == 1){
            ++total;
        }
    }

    for(int j = 1; j < X.ncol(); j++) {
      Rcpp::NumericVector b = X[j];
      int B = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
          if(a[i] == 1){
              B += b[i];
          }
      }
      probs[j - 1] = (double)B/(double)total;
    }

    return probs;
  }
')

Get_Prob(df[-1])
#> [1] 0.2 0.4 0.4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This will only compute the means of 3 columns, it is not general purpose.

Comment: I have added a general purpose solution based on the posted code.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas for the edit. Rcpp is not my strong suit, so I thought I'd just throw the idea out there. You did a good job taking it to the finish.